# Let B = ∗, a set with only one element. Given any set A, prove that A × B equivalent to A.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I really have no idea where I should start with this proof. Could I please have some guidance?

Comment: How do you define equivalence of sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that equivalent means that the sets have the same cardinality. Take $B=\{x\}$ and $A$ an arbitrary set. If $A=\emptyset$, then clearly $A\times B=A=\emptyset$ and, thus, the sets have the same cardinality. If $A\neq\emptyset$, then take $f:A\times B\to A$ defined by $f(y,x)=y$. First, the function is injective because if we take two elements $(y_1,x),(y_2,x)\in A\times B$ and $(y_1,x)\neq(y_2,x)$, then, necessarily, $y_1\neq y_2$. Thus, $f(y_1,x)=y_1\neq y_2=f(y_2,x)$. Clearly is onto because if we take an arbitrary $y\in A$, then, the pair $(y,x)$ works: clearly $f(y,x)=y$.
Therefore, $f$ is a bijection. We conclude that $|A\times B|=|A|$

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that there exists a bijection between $A\times B$ and $A$ try to find two mappings $f:A\times B\rightarrow A$ and $g:A\rightarrow A\times B$ (there actually is only one possible choice in general) and show that $f\circ g= id_A$ and $g\circ f=id_{A\times B}$.